# Can't extend superclass when using @Inject with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Contrary to everything I've read, I seem unable to extend a class where the base class requires an injected OpaqueToken reference.

Example:

```
@Component({})
export class StructureBase_Cmp {
    constructor(private constants:App_Const){
    }
}
```

In this example, `App_Const` comes from an OpaqueToken that is provided in the module as such:

```
providers: [
    {provide: App_Const, useValue: Constants}
],
```

I am aware that for whatever reason you need to call @Inject, thus changing the first example to this:

```
@Component({})
export class StructureBase_Cmp {
    constructor(@Inject(App_Const) private constants){
    }
}
```

This works fine. What does not work fine is trying to extend that class because it complains that "private constants" is of a different type in the derived class:

```
@Component({})
export class Hero_Cmp extends StructureBase_Cmp{
    constructor(@Inject(App_Const) protected constants) {
        super(constants);
    }
}
```

However, I can't change the super class to this:

```
@Component({})
export class StructureBase_Cmp {
    constructor(private constants:App_Const){
    }
}
```

because.... what, App_Const is an OpaqueToken and not a defined Type? Despite the docs, I'm extremely confused because this feels like some flavor of this should work right out of the box.

tldr:
I want to extend a class that requires an injected item that is derived from an OpaqueToken, however in order to do so I need to use @Inject on the derived class, which for whatever reason breaks the parent class.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use other parameter name in `Hero_Cmp`? like `constructor(@Inject(App_Const) protected appConstants) { super(appConstants); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the issue is not related to angular nor IoC. It is just an typescript compiler check ([observe it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20StructureBase_Cmp%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20constants)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Hero_Cmp%20extends%20StructureBase_Cmp%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(protected%20constants)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(constants)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
export class StructureBase_Cmp {
    constructor(private constants){
    }
}

export class Hero_Cmp extends StructureBase_Cmp{
    constructor(protected constants) {
        super(constants);
    }
}
```

will produce error:

> Class 'Hero_Cmp' incorrectly extends base class 'StructureBase_Cmp'.
>   Property 'constants' is private in type 'StructureBase_Cmp' but not in
>   type 'Hero_Cmp'. class Hero_Cmp

because parent has a property **`private`**, while child **`protected`**. That does not make sense.

just make it protected as well

```
export class StructureBase_Cmp {
    constructor(protected constants){ // also protected
    }
}

export class Hero_Cmp extends StructureBase_Cmp{
    constructor(protected constants) {
        super(constants);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was part of it. I switched them both to protected but still got errors. However, the errors were related to Typescripts finnicky-ness around load ordering, which wasn't too hard to fix.
Thanks!